# How to enable Banner image on Phone

Tags: magento-1.8

The banner of this magento site (http://mushkaperfumes.com/) isn't displaying when viewing with mobile phone. Please how can i make it display in the home page of the mobile phone view. The version is Magento 1.8.1.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you specify your real problem. Currently your website banner show in phone. You have problem of responsiveness of site.

Comment: The banner doesn't display on the phone.. The banner with the Perfume pictures and descriptions are not displaying on the phone..What i want is what to do to make it display on the phone. Thanks

Comment: Share the screen-sort of issue, because I am not found issue.

Comment: Hello, Please find the screenshot for the mobile view.  http://mushkaperfumes.com/media/mobileview.png    
Thanks

Comment: Hello, Please find the screenshot for the mobile view.  http://mushkaperfumes.com/media/mobileview.png    
Thanks